# Write ID3 Tags with OBJC

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, tags, id3

So I need to write new ID3 tags to audio file. I try to use 2 methods.

**First**.

I used Core Audio, and could only to read tags, like this

```
-(void)getInformationAudioFile {
//get title and artist information audio file

//read raw ID3Tag size
UInt32 id3DataSize = 0;
char *rawID3Tag = NULL;
AudioFileGetPropertyInfo(inputFile,
                         kAudioFilePropertyID3Tag,
                         &id3DataSize,
                         NULL);

rawID3Tag = (char *)malloc(id3DataSize);

//read raw ID3Tag
AudioFileGetProperty(inputFile,
                     kAudioFilePropertyID3Tag,
                     &id3DataSize,
                     rawID3Tag);

CFDictionaryRef piDict = nil;
UInt32 piDataSize = sizeof(piDict);

//this key returns some other dictionary, which works also in iPod library
AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_ID3TagToDictionary,
                       id3DataSize,
                       rawID3Tag,
                       &piDataSize,
                       &piDict);

free(rawID3Tag);

NSDictionary *tagsDictionary = (__bridge NSDictionary*)piDict;

NSLog (@"dictionary: %@", tagsDictionary);

self->_title = [tagsDictionary objectForKey:@"TIT2"];
if(!self.title)
    self->_title = self.url.path.lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension;

self->_artist = [tagsDictionary objectForKey:@"TPE1"];
if(!self.artist)
    self->_artist = @"Unknown artist";

self->_album = [tagsDictionary objectForKey:@"TALB"];
if(!self.album)
    self->_album = @"Unknown album";

self->_genre = [tagsDictionary objectForKey:@"TCON"];
if(!self.genre)
    self->_genre = @"Unknown genre";

self->_year = [tagsDictionary objectForKey:@"TYER"];
if(!self.year)
    self->_year = @"Unknown year";

CFRelease(piDict); }
```

And I dont know how to change tag of file.

**Second.**

So i found another method using [TagLib](https://taglib.github.io/)
And i found much examples, where guys using this library and objc read files. And didnt find examples how to write tags.

So i want to know how can i write ID3 tags?

Sorry for my english.